# Creating a list with names and indicate the double inputted names

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

So i have been trying to make a a list of names in JavaScript. I have added the text box and the button to add names and that works perfectly, but now i need to do a check on that list and when i have entered the name "John" for example twice, there has to come in my list "John 2 times", when entered three times "John 3 times" and so on.. I am really stuck on this part and hope you can help me out with this.

```js
"use strict";

let voornaam = [];
document.getElementById("toevoegen").onclick=function(){
    const voornaamInput = document.getElementById("voornaam");
    const voornaam = voornaamInput.value;
    toevoegen(voornaam);
    voornaamInput.value="";
    voornaamInput.focus();
}

//add name//
function toevoegen (voornaam){
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText=voornaam;
    document.getElementById("voornamen").appendChild(li);
}

//do the check//
function controle (voornaam) {

}
```

```html
<label>Voornaam: <input id="voornaam" autofocus></label>
<button id="toevoegen">Toevoegen</button>
<ul id="voornamen">
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi can you add the HTML to your question?

Comment: Hi @TessavWalstijn I have added my html code to the toppic :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've made some changes to the code for you. I've added a bunch of commentary to help you learn some new tricks.

Using the right tool for the job here, in my opinion, would be an `object` rather than an `array`. If you haven't got your head around objects yet, do so, they are great when you understand them.

```
'use strict';

// let voornaam = [];
let names = {
    Steve: 1,
    Mathias: 2,
};

document.getElementById('toevoegen').onclick = function () {
    const voornaamInput = document.getElementById('voornaam');
    const voornaam = voornaamInput.value;
    tallyName(voornaam);
    displayList();
    voornaamInput.value = '';
    voornaamInput.focus();
};

// Tally name
function tallyName(name) {
    // Check name is not empty
    if (name !== '') {
        // Ternary operator - check the name is in our object and has a value of 0 or more.
        // If its already there, add 1, else set it to 0.
        // Try adding this without the check, you will see that you get unwanted behaviour such as NaN etc.
        names[name] > -1 ? (names[name] += 1) : (names[name] = 0);

        // Above line is equivalent to:
        // if (names[name] > -1) {
        //  names[name] = names[name] + 1;
        // } else {
        //  names[name] = 0;
        // }
    } else {
        console.log('Invalid input');
    }
}

// Set list
function displayList() {
    // Get list
    const list = document.getElementById('voornamen');

    // Remove existing list
    while (list.firstChild) {
        list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }

    // This may be a little confusing to start but is a great tool.
    // It cycles the object and reads the key and its corresponding value
    // Object.entries(names) would look like this: [['Steve', 0],['James',2]]
    // So the first loop we get ['Steve', 0] and "destructure" it with the ([key, value])
    console.log(Object.entries(names));
    Object.entries(names).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        // To see what this is doing.
        console.log(k, v);

        // Create new item
        let newItem = document.createElement('li');
        // Set text
        newItem.innerText = k + ': ' + v;
        // Add to document
        list.appendChild(newItem);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Steve,

i want to thank you for helping me out with this. I will get started on the Objects part. For me this was the first time i posted a question on this website but i will keep it in mind that i will put everything in English so it is better to understand.

Thank you very much! ^^

Comment: No worries. Have a look at these courses: https://zerotomastery.io/promotions/. A bloke named Andrei makes them and he is great at teaching, through that link you can choose from the two links that will give you a cheaper price.... "The Complete Web Developer in 2020: Zero to Mastery" is the course you should look at and it looks like its about $11 AUD from where im looking. You will learn soooo much and his discord community will put you in touch with a lot of helpful people. I've done about 4 of his courses so far.

Comment: Hello Steve,

I will take a look at it! Thank you so much for this!